# Why does my Magento while opening on MAMP, linking to my Domain?

Tags: git, magento, e-commerce, mamp

I am trying to set up my Magento Store (which is currently installed at my cloud hosting server) in local MAMP Server. I want to develop it from now on on my local machine and to push changes using git to the one on my server. I've *git cloned* my git repository in my htdocs folder. Afterwards I have open MAMP, but I am not able to open my Shop locally using: 
`localhost:8888/my_shop`.
Every time I run this, Chrome is linking to my Domain on which my Shop is currently running online. How can I solve this? Do I need to change the: 

`web/unsecure/base_url`
 and the

`web/secure/base_url`
 on `core_config_data` in my database? If yes, to which URL should I change these, to `localhost:8888/my_shop`?

Thank you!

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: Still the same problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a query like this to do this for you in all relevant places, especially if you are running multiple websites or stores under same domain. Replace field_name and URLs with actual data (if i recall correctly field_name is `value`)

```
UPDATE core_config_data set field_name = replace(field_name, 'http://live.url', 'http://local.url') WHERE field_name LIKE 'http://live.url%';
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, change those values to `localhost:8888/my_shop`. Magento will try to resolve to those URLs in `core_config_data` - just make sure to change these back once you deploy! This is assuming that you are *not* sharing a database with your production server and have a local copy of it running on your machine.